# Applying strikeout in a specific part of RichTextBox (WinForm)

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

What is the simplest way to apply strikeout in a specific part of a text?

For example:

```
rxtTest.text = "Stackoverflow is a very good site" 'Apply strikeout just on 'very'
```

Comment: in what context? Webform? Winform? Graphics object? RichTextBox? the string doesnt use a Font, so there are many many answers.

Comment: Sorry Plutonix ... Thanks to remember me

Comment: So answer Plutonix' question, i.e. what type of `TextBox`?  If it's WinForms then the answer is that you can't.  There's just one `Font` property so only one style can be used for the entire `Text`.  In WinForms, and most other technologies as well, you would have to use a `RichTextBox` instead, or perhaps multiple `Label`'s or just GDI+ if the text is read-only.

Comment: hum..thanks jmcilhinney I had been using a WinForms.I'll perform my searches on RichTextBox and GDI+

Comment: jmcilhinney i got it! THANKS!!! =D

Answer (score 1):

```
'rxtTest = My WinForm RichTextBox
'rxtTest.Text = "Stackoverflow is a very good site"
'text selected = "very"

Private Sub rxtTest_MouseCaptureChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rxtTest.MouseCaptureChanged
    Dim f As New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Strikeout)
    rxtTest.SelectionFont = f
End Sub

'After this code my text selected ("very") will be strikeout
```

Comment: I assume that you solved the problem yourself. As vb.net noob, I am missing in this answer is to what part of the text strikethrough is applied to. I am guessing to what you select? Could you please edit your answer and add this information?

Comment: @Sumurai8 better? sorry...i'm new on stackoverflow

Comment: I would personally move the part that tells what the code does outside the code block, but anyhow this has made it clearer. Thanks :-)